# source /bin/activate activates the system interpreter not the venv one

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I run source bin/activate , the virtual environment seems to be activated since I can see (venv). However when I run which python , I realise its using the system wide interpreter i.e /usr/bin/python and therefore any modules in install are installed system wide. I created the virtual environment using Pycharm and when I my scripts through Pycharm, it works fine. But right now I need to run them through terminal and therefore I need the virtual environment.

Comment: Are you sure packages are installed system wide, or is that a suspicion? Meaning, if the venv was set up with ` --system-site-packages`, it would make sense to see system wide packages, but new ones would still be installed within the venv

Comment: Are you doing exactly this?
open terminal, `source bin/activate`, [(venv) should be displaying before user name.] `python file.py`

Comment: I am curious as to why "which python"  returns the system wide interpreter despite venv being active. That is why I assume that its packages have been installed system wide.

Comment: Your question title says `/bin/activate` which is distinct from the relative path `./bin/activate`. Which one are you actually running? (I'm guessing the latter; but then please [edit] your question to fix the title.)

Comment: @tripleee I am running `source /bin/activate` and I get (venv) before the user name which means venv is active, In which case I would expect `which python` to return the venv interpreter.

Comment: Then that's your bug. `/bin/activate` is either an error or the wrong path. You need to be running `source bin/activate` (without a slash before the `bin`) to run the specific `activate` inside the virtual environment (aka `./bin/activate`).

Comment: This is speculaive, but if you ran `virtualenv` without arguments in the root directory `/` as `root` when you set up the system, it will have created a system-wide `bin/activate` in the root directory, which then of course is actually executable as `/bin/activate` and refers to the system default Python as the one it invokes from the virtual environment. (Not entirely sure how this plays out -- some things still don't make sense.)

Comment: It still activates the system wide interpreter even when I run `source bin/activate` , running this inside the venv directory. Something is probably wrong with my paths. I will delete and create a new venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create virtualenv `$ virtualenv env && source env/bin/activate` then `which python` would show the right python here. You only need care while doing this. Sometimes you have to remove completely the `env`, close and restart the terminal and even `source deactivate`. Those are options.  [Virtualenv guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#next-steps)

EDIT:
There is no need to `source deactivate`. Deactivate is enough

Comment: No, when you have run `activate` it defines a shell function `deactivate` which knows how to restore things to how they were before you ran `activate`.

Comment: I removed the `venv` completely and created again. This time it points to the correct interpreter. Thanks.